# Парсинг твитов пользователя

Tags: python, веб-программирование, парсер, твиттер

Хочу распарсить все твиты, но выводятся только 18 из 1152.

```
import  urllib
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://twitter.com/bigladasha'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

count = 0                                           # счетчик
all_tweets_count = soup.find('a',{'class':'ProfileNav-stat ProfileNav-stat--link u-borderUserColor u-textCenter js-tooltip js-nav'})\
    .findAll('span')[1].text                        # количество твитов
all_tweets_count = all_tweets_count.replace(',','') # 1,152 -> 1152


while count < all_tweets_count:
    print soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'js-tweet-text-container'})[count].find('p').text
    print '---------------------------------------------------------------'
    count += 1
```

Comment: Это происходит из-за того, что Вы находитесь на первой странице твитов. Нужно переходить на следующую страницу или как-то иначе подгружать твиты следующей страницы.

Comment: Вариант с использованием Twitter API намеренно не рассматриваете?

Comment: Почему не используете API? В этих ваших интернетах есть много примеров уже готовых. Вот что я нашёл примерно за 7 секунд: https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496

Comment: в принципе, есть готовое решение: https://twitter.sneakin.info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любой парсинг Web'а разбивается об лёд, если есть API, как предложил xEdelweiss !

Однако если необходим именно парсинг, то вот:

Обычный HTML парсинг не вытянет вам содержимое спрятанное за JavaScript'ом.
Здесь нужен кардинально другой подход. Что-бы полноценно работать с JavaScript'ом, и получать итоги его преобразований вам нужно работать не через Суп и urllib, а через браузер. Сколько бы вы не "крутили" страницу вниз, твиты не добавятся, так как они прилетают по JavaScript'у.

У меня аналогичная ситуация решается связкой Selenium+PhantomJS. Это управляющий драйвер (Selenium) и безголовый браузер (безголовым PhantomJS называется потому, что ему не нужен экран что-бы отрендерить страницу, всё происходит в строке).

Итак, если вы решили всерьёз запарсить твиты со страницы, и вас ничего не остановит))))), то вот мой вариант):

1. Устанавливаете в Python библиотеку selenium (`pip install selenium`)
2. Скачиваете PhantomJS, и помещаете его в PATH (http://phantomjs.org/)
3. Пишите код)))

Вот этот код можете использовать как "шапку", в ней особо ничего менять не придётся:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

ua = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
ua["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36")
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=ua)
browser.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
browser.get('https://twitter.com/bigladasha')
time.sleep(10)
browser.save_screenshot('screen_test_twit.png')
```

Дальше описать взаимодействие со страницей, поможет справка по селениуму (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

**P.S.** Предложенный код `browser.save_screenshot('screen_test_twit.png')` сохранит скриншот страницы твиттера , которая загружается в самом начале и до прокручивания, её ещё нужно будет прокрутить вниз, что-бы JavaScript подгружал остальные твиты.

**P.S.2** Так же вам нужно будет прокручивать страницу до тех пор, пока не прилетит самый первый твит автора, и только тогда получать нужную вам информацию в переменные

**P.S.3** В примере используется `time.sleep(10)` только как временный костыль, правильней использовать явное ожидание "Explicit Waits" (оно описано в справке к селениуму по ссылке сверху)

**P.S.4-Самый главный постскриптум**

Предложенный мною вариант не является 100% истинным, другие знающие люди могут предложить вам другие связки и другие методы.
Но на мой взгляд у всех методов будет один принцип:

Обрабатывать динамическое содержимое JavaScript'а в Web'е возможно только через приложения предназначенные для этого, то есть через браузеры.

**Совет:**
Что-бы узнать как поведёт себя сайт с отключенным JavaScript'ом используйте дополнение NoScript в браузере Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Обычно можно и самому сходить за данными, как скрипт.